# Get exit code from subshell through the pipes

Tags: bash, pipe, exit-code, tee, subshell

How can I get exit code of `wget` from the subshell process?

So, main problem is that `$?` is equal 0. Where can `$?=8` be founded?

```
$> OUT=$( wget -q "http://budueba.com/net" | tee -a "file.txt" ); echo "$?"
0
```

It works without `tee`, actually.

```
$> OUT=$( wget -q "http://budueba.com/net" ); echo "$?"
8
```

But `${PIPESTATUS}` array (I'm not sure it's related to that case) also does not contain that value.

```
$> OUT=$( wget -q "http://budueba.com/net" | tee -a "file.txt" ); echo "${PIPESTATUS[1]}"    

$> OUT=$( wget -q "http://budueba.com/net" | tee -a "file.txt" ); echo "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
0

$> OUT=$( wget -q "http://budueba.com/net" | tee -a "file.txt" ); echo "${PIPESTATUS[-1]}"
0
```

So, my question is - how can I get `wget`'s exit code through `tee` and subshell?

If it could be helpful, my bash version is `4.2.20`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By using `$()` you are (effectively) creating a subshell. Thus the `PIPESTATUS` instance you need to look at is only available inside your subshell (i.e. inside the `$()`), since environment variables do not propagate from child to parent processes.

You could do something like this:

```
  OUT=$( wget -q "http://budueba.com/net" | tee -a "file.txt"; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]} );
  echo $? # prints exit code of wget.
```

You can achieve a similar behavior by using the following:

```
  OUT=$(wget -q "http://budueba.com/net")
  rc=$? # save exit code for later
  echo "$OUT" | tee -a "file.txt"
```

Comment: But is it possible to export all `${PIPESTATUS}` array up to parent shell?

Comment: That is not how [`export`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Environment) works - it exports variables as environment variables for *child* processes (from the parent).

Comment: Here is a [solution for bringing the entire `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` array into the parent script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41716616/get-exit-codes-of-a-pipe-when-output-is-assigned-to-variable-command-substituti/44314883#44314883). It involves adding it to the end of the created variable and then pulling it off into a new array.

Answer (score 8):

Beware of this when using `local` variables:

```
local OUT=$(command; exit 1)
echo $? # 0

OUT=$(command; exit 1)
echo $? # 1
```

Comment: Declaring `local OUT` then assigning `OUT=` on a new line correctly sets the exit code variable `$?` if you don't want scope creep.

Comment: ShellCheck points out this exact issue, so simply heed the warning from ShellCheck and you should be good to go ...

Answer (score 0):

For everyone using `bash`. I think that by far cleanest solution to **both** **get output value** and **each exit status** in pipe is this.

1. A one-time preparation. Enable `lastpipe` shell option. It allows to get value from the last command in pipe without using subshell. If you're in an interactive shell, also disable job control: `set +m` (The latter isn't needed for scripts - job control is disabled there by default.)

   ```
   shopt -s lastpipe
   set +m
   ```
2. `read` the value into your variable, and use PIPESTATUS naturally. E.g.

   ```
   grep -E "\S" "file.txt" | sort | uniq | read -d '' RES
   # 'read' exit status 1 means all input was read till EOF, we're OK with that
   if (( PIPESTATUS[0] > 1 || PIPESTATUS[1] > 0 || PIPESTATUS[2] > 0 || PIPESTATUS[3] > 1 )); then
     echo "ERROR"
   else
     echo "$RES"
   fi
   ```

The above reads all non-empty lines from "file.txt", sorts them and removes duplicates. In this example we have custom processing of exit codes: `grep` exit status 1 means no lines were selected, we're OK with that; `read` exit status 1 is expected for saving multi-line output (at least, I don't know another clean way to do it). Clean means without cluttering the code just to avoid the exit status of 1 of `read`.

NOTE: the `read -d ''` option is used to read all the input into our variable (by disabling delimiter `read` stops at, which by default is a newline symbol). This is how we save multi-line output. If your pipe has just one line then you can use plain `read RES` (and likely can change expected exit status from read to 0 and not 1 as above).

Answer (score -1):

Copy the PIPESTATUS array first. Any reads destroy the current state.

```
declare -a PSA  
cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3  
PSA=( "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" )
```

I used fifos to solve the sub-shell/PIPESTATUS problem. See
[bash pipestatus in backticked command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776100/bash-pipestatus-in-backticked-command)
I also found these useful: 
[bash script: how to save return value of first command in a pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955644/bash-script-how-to-save-return-value-of-first-command-in-a-pipeline/5956065#5956065)
and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another/70675#70675

Comment: The code you provided doesn't answer the question. If the multiple links have the answer about getting the result from sub shell + getting the exit codes then please provide an excerpt right in the answer.