# bash get an exit code from a subshell and pipe

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script `java_debug` to log all java executions (standard and error console):

```
#! /bin/bash
echo param1: $1
echo param2: $2

(java HelloWorld "$@" 2>&1 ) | tee /tmp/log.txt
```

I run it:

```
$ java_debug v1 "v2 with space"
param1: v1
param2: v2 wirh space
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld

$ echo $?
0
```

in this example, java cannot find the HelloWorld class, and so it shows an error.
However, the error is lost in $? (we get 0 instead of 1) because of the subshell and/or the pipe.

I need that java_debug returns the same exit code as the java execution

How to fix this script?

note: I could use the `script` command instead of `2>&1 | tee`, but unfortunately the implementation of the script command changes in different systems (the script parameters are not the same in redhat than in OSX).

note: I am aware that bash is an horrible language and it should not be used; but I have no choice in this case.

Comment: `bash` is a fine language when used for its intended purpose.

Answer (score 5):

found answer here: [Get exit code from subshell through the pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277827/getting-exit-code-from-subshell-through-the-pipes)

in my case:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo param1: $1
echo param2: $2

(java HelloWorld "$@" 2>&1 ) | tee /tmp/log.txt
exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```