# Return status of command returning data into variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables, return-value

how can I get status from command, which is assigned into variable?

For example:

```
#! /bin/bash

### GET PID
GETPID=$(ps aux | grep "bash" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2 }')

if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
    echo "status OK"
else 
    echo "status NOT OK"
fi
```

Comment: If you want to get your current process id, you can use `$$` --> `echo $$`. Regarding the question itself, your `if` condition checks an integer, so that you want to say `if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]"`... that is, use `-eq` to check equality in integers.

Comment: I don't understand the question here...do you want the output of the command, or the exit status, or both (or what)?

Comment: @fedorqui  - Thanks for the comments relating to the comparison integer. But i also need in my script check if any command return bad status or no (for example somebody who run script are not allowed run other script...).

Comment: @TomFenech - I want the output of the command and the exit status (both)

Comment: You already have them in that case - the output is in `$GETPID` and the exit status is in `$?`. What's the problem?

Comment: Just in passing - if you have `pgrep`, you can replace that pipeline with something shorter and more reliable.

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277827/getting-exit-code-from-subshell-through-the-pipes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
PID=($(pidof bash))
if [[ ${#PID[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "status OK"
else
    echo "status not OK"
fi
```