# In bash how do I exit a script from a function that is piped by tee?

Tags: bash, function, exit, tee, subshell

I'm trying to understand why whenever I'm using `function 2>&1 | tee -a $LOG` tee creates a subshell in function that can't be exited by simple `exit 1` (and if I'm not using `tee` it works fine). Below the example:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG=/root/log.log

function first()
{
echo "Function 1 - I WANT to see this."
exit 1
}

function second()
{
echo "Function 2 - I DON'T WANT to see this."
exit 1
}
first 2>&1 | tee -a $LOG
second 2>&1 | tee -a $LOG
```

**Output:**

```
[root@linuxbox ~]# ./1.sh  
Function 1 - I WANT to see this.
Function 2 - I DON'T WANT to see this.
```

So. if I remove `| tee -a $LOG` part, it's gonna work as expected (script will be exited in the first function).

Can you, please, explain how to overcome this and exit properly in the function while being able to tee output?

Comment: "creates a subshell in function" Well, you already said that. Why? Because all simple commands in a pipeline except the last one are executed in subshells (the last one depends on an option or something — I forgot). Why? Because. As for how to exit properly, check exit status (if `pipefail` is set) or `PIPESTATUS` after the pipeline.

Comment: Follow-up on comment above: the option I forgot is `lastpipe`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9277827/951890

Comment: 4ae1e1, Thank you too. As with a help of you pointer I also learned about PIPESTATUS, and apparently the workaround:

`function PIPE_STAT()
    {
    if [[ $PIPESTATUS -ne 0 ]]; then
    exit 1
    fi
}`
Can be used and placed after each `function 2>&1 | tee -a $LOG` to verify the status and exit if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a pipeline, the function is run in a subshell, and if you `exit` from a subshell, only the subshell will be affected, not the parent shell.

```
printPid(){ echo $BASHPID; }

printPid #some value
printPid #same value
printPid | tee #an implicit subshell -- different value
( printPid ) #an explicit subshell -- also a different value
```

If, instead of `aFunction | tee` you do:

```
aFunction > >(tee)
```

it'll be essential the same, except `aFunction` won't run in a subshell, and thus will be able to affect the current environment (set variables, call exit, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, PSkocik, that is really the needed solution!

Comment: I am getting error when I use `aFunction > >(tee)`. Please elaborate the solution. Am I not getting it.

Comment: @Makesh What shell you on. `>(tee)` only works in "advanced" shells like bash, ksh, or zsh. Simple POSIX shells like dash don't have it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `PIPESTATUS` to retrieve the exit status of the first command in the pipeline.

```
first 2>&1 | tee -a $LOG; test ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 || exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
second 2>&1 | tee -a $LOG; test ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 || exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tell bash to fail if anything in the pipeline fails with `set -e -o pipefail`:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
LOG=~/log.log

set -e -o pipefail

function first()
{
echo "Function 1 - I WANT to see this."
exit 1
}

function second()
{
echo "Function 2 - I DON'T WANT to see this."
exit 1
}
first 2>&1 | tee -a $LOG
second 2>&1 | tee -a $LOG
$ ./test.sh
Function 1 - I WANT to see this.
```

Comment: Thanks! I also like this solution - elegant, but works only on bash v3 and higher (apparently).

Comment: bash v3 was released in 2004.  I think you'll be OK.

Comment: set -e might be risky. In your script, if there is any error anywhere, it will abort the script.