# Exit whole script from code block { }

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have the following script:

```
{
   ...
   many commands and printing
   ...
   if something goes wrong I do exit 1
} 2>&1 | tee test.log
```

But the problem is that the `{}` block is exiting and not the whole script.

How can I make the whole script exit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line after your tee command:

`test ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 || exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}`

Reference Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34386000/2357256